# Changing links of chart connected with another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

since 2 days i'm stuck with a problem that I cannot solve. The problem is as follows:

I have created a sheet where you have mulitple (around 25 objects, which are mostly charts, but also connected tables), what I want to achieve is to create changable links between these charts, because they can be used in many different folders... For example table can look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/swpGQ.jpg

Formula: `=Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12|'C:\Users\MainUser\New\AnotherExcel.xlsm'!'!Data - Subscriptions!W28K36:W30K39'`

What I want to achieve is to create a macro that changes this link like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Formula = _
    "=Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12|'" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\AnotherExcel.xlsm'!'!Data - Subscriptions!W28K36:W30K39'"
End Sub
```

But the problem is when I try to do anything similiar to this I get an error like this:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

And also like this:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Setting the property Formula of class Rectangle is not possible
```

**Another important thing:** When I change the value manually in the formula bar in excel it also changes link in **Data -> Connections -> Edit links**, so it's great. Then I also recorded a macro basing on this and I received:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 23")).Select
    Selection.Formula = _
        "=Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12|'C:\Users\MainUser\New\TestingFormula\AnotherExcel.xlsm'!'!Data - Subscriptions!W28K36:W30K39'"
```

But when I wanted to run it I just received 2nd error, which is extremely confusing, since it should just change my formula. I'm not sure if it's significant information, but I use Excel 2010.

Since I actually can't overcome this problem I want to ask you for any directions or solution to my problem.

Comment: Try this `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Formula = "='" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "[AnotherExcel.xlsm]Appendix-3C'!Data - Subscriptions!W28K36:W30K39"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately still I receive an error like: Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Is this Shape pasted in MS Word?

Comment: Nope, the table actually lies in another MS Excel File. It works like this: I have one main file, let's call it Main... Besides I have also 4 different files: AnotherFile1, AnotherFile2, AnotherFile3, AnotherFile4. From files AnotherFile 1 - 4 I take charts, tables and PasteSpecial (with link) to file Main. If you need any more informations please do tell me.

Comment: I am curious why do you have `Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12` in the formula

Comment: Well, it is added automatically by excel after I pasted is as a link. You can try it as well. To do it you need to have 2 different workbooks, then copy a chart from wb1, then right click -> Paste special... -> Paste link -> Microsoft Excel chart object

Comment: paste Link is disabled for me. which MS Office version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS Excel 2010 (I have stated it in my question)... Well it is disabled normally, but you need to have 2 seperate worksheets placed next to each other. Then it starts working... At least for me.

Comment: Sorry I missed the 2010 part. Well that is not enabled for me. I am using 2013.

Comment: There is a guide to do it in 2013. I'm putting it [here](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/word2013/embedding-an-excel-chart/1/)

Comment: One moment... I asked you if you were using MS Word....

Comment: True, you asked and I have answered: "Nope, the table actually lies in another MS Excel File." So it means that I pasted it to another Excel File...

Comment: If there is no word involved then I am curious as to why did you share a MS word link with me :D or am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh my god, I have sent the wrong one, I'm so sorry... Ugh... Never mind then. I don't know why you cannot use paste as a link then :/